# tabular can't caption is separated

Tags: tables, captions

I'm creating a table like this:

```
\captionof{table}{caption}
\begin{tabular}{@{} *5l @{}}\toprule
\emph{header1} & \emph{header2} & \emph{header3} \\\midrule
item1 & v1  & v2   \\
item2 & v1  & v2   \\
item2 & v1  & v2   \\
\hline
\label{table:label}
\end{tabular}
```

This way the caption gets separated from the table and if it reaches the end of the page the table might go to the next page while its caption remains on the previous page. If I move the caption inside tabular I get an error:

```
You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders.
\caption@hrule ->\hrule
```

and if I use \caption instead:

```
Package caption Error: \caption outside float
```

I've added these lines to use caption for my tables:

```
\usepackage[hypcap]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{name=table}
```

Comment: Are you using the [`revtex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/revtex) document class (see [Non break space between figure and caption for figure float `h`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/183210/5764))?

Comment: What is that `\label` doing inside the `tabular`, move it right after `\captionof`. Why are your using `\captionof` in the first place? Place it inside the `table` env and use `\caption`

Comment: Place caption and table in a `minipage`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you considered using the [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package?

This is your example a little re-arranged:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{position=top,labelfont={sc},textfont={sl}}

\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman {table}}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Table's caption}\label{tab:label}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \toprule
        \emph{header1} & \emph{header2} & \emph{header3} \\
        \midrule
        item1 & v1  & v2   \\
        item2 & v1  & v2   \\
        item2 & v1  & v2   \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: He's already using `booktabs`, partially at least. (Note the `\toprule`.)

Comment: I didn't noticed, I saw the `\hline` at the end.

Comment: yea I forgot to mention I'm using booktabs as well. But this one works fine. Just one more thing. My doc is not in english but I want numerals in my table to be latin. How can I do that?

Comment: You can do it with `\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}}`.  See my updated answer